# Weird behavior of BASH glob/regex ranges

Tags: regex, bash, shell, cygwin, glob

I'm seeing BASH bracket ranges (e.g. [A-Z]) behaving in an unexpected way.
Is there's an explanation for such behavior, or it is a bug?

Let's say I have a variable, from which I want to strip all uppercase letters:

```
$ var='ABCDabcd0123'
$ echo "${var//[A-Z]/}"
```

The result I get is this:

```
a0123
```

If I do it with `sed`, I get an expected result:

```
$ echo "${var}" | sed 's/[A-Z]//g'
abcd0123
```

The same seems to be the case for BASH built-in regex match:

```
$ [[ a =~ [A-Z] ]] ; echo $?
1
$ [[ b =~ [A-Z] ]] ; echo $?
0
```

If I check all lowercase letters from 'a' to 'z', it seems that only 'a' is an exception:

```
$ for l in {a..z}; do [[ $l =~ [A-Z] ]] || echo $l; done
a
```

I do not have case-insensitive matching enabled, and even if I did, it should not make letter 'a' behave differently:

```
$ shopt -p nocasematch
shopt -u nocasematch
```

For the reference, I'm using Cygwin, and I don't see this behavior on any other machine:

```
$ uname
CYGWIN_NT-6.3
$ bash --version | head -1
GNU bash, version 4.3.46(7)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)
$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

**EDIT:**

I've found the exact same issue reported here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/120687
So, I guess it's a bug(?) of "en_GB.UTF-8" collation, but not BASH itself.
Setting `LC_COLLATE=C` indeed solves this.

Comment: @Inian I've added it to the question

Comment: @anubhava I know, but it doesn't. That's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227070/why-does-a-z-match-lowercase-letters-in-bash

Comment: @Mat: That is a very good matching thread however this behavior cannot be reproduced with OP's locale settings.

Comment: @Mat thank you for the link. Indeed, setting LC_COLLATE=C makes it behave as expected. But I'm still wondering why it works as it is with LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8". Is there any way to know exactly what characters will be included in specified range for specific LC_COLLATE value?

Comment: Yes `LC_ALL=C` should be able to fix it but as I commented above we cannot reproduce the problem using OP's locale settings.

Comment: @Thunderbeef: Use the `POSIX` character classes! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *certainly* had to do with setting of your `locale`. An excerpt from the [GNU bash man page under Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)

> [..] in the default `C` locale, `[a-dx-z]` is equivalent to `[abcdxyz]`. Many locales sort characters in dictionary order, and in these locales `[a-dx-z]` is typically not equivalent to `[abcdxyz]`; it might be equivalent to `[aBbCcDdxXyYz]`, for example. To obtain the traditional interpretation of ranges in bracket expressions, you can force the use of the C locale by setting the `LC_COLLATE` or `LC_ALL` environment variable to the value `C`, or enable the `globasciiranges` shell option.[..]

Use the `POSIX` character-classess, `[[:upper:]]` in this case or change your `locale` setting `LC_ALL` or `LC_COLLATE` to `C` as mentioned above.

```
LC_ALL=C var='ABCDabcd0123'
echo "${var//[A-Z]/}"
abcd0123
```

Also, your *negative* test to do upper-case check will fail for all the lower case letters when setting this locale hence printing the letters,

```
LC_ALL=C; for l in {a..z}; do [[ $l =~ [A-Z] ]] || echo $l; done
```

Also, under the above locale setting

```
[[ a =~ [A-Z] ]] ; echo $?
1
[[ b =~ [A-Z] ]] ; echo $?
1
```

but will be true for all *lower-case* ranges,

```
[[ a =~ [a-z] ]] ; echo $?
0
[[ b =~ [a-z] ]] ; echo $?
0
```

---

Said this, all these can be avoided by using the `POSIX` specified character classes, under a new shell *without* any `locale` setting,

```
echo "${var//[[:upper:]]/}"
abcd0123
```

and

```
for l in {a..z}; do [[ $l =~ [[:upper:]] ]] || echo $l; done
```